# Argument for flux quantization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, superconductivity, many-body, vortex

I am reading P. Coleman's Introduction to many-body physics. Coleman claims that At large distances, energetics favor a reduction of the circulation to zero
$$\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\omega=0$$
where
$$\omega=\oint d\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{v}_s=\oint d\mathbf{x}\cdot
[\frac{\hbar}{m}\nabla\phi-\frac{e^*}{m}\mathbf{A}].$$

I do not know what is the precise argument to $\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\omega=0$.

Comment: It is energetics: there is a term $(\nabla \phi- e^*/\hbar \mathbf{A})^2$ in the Ginzburg-Landau action, so to minimize this term your $\omega$ better vanishes in the large distance.

Comment: Thanks. Why do we need large $R$?